# What is the proper way in MySQL to SET a column to a value of a variable when using UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a column for a certain user with PHP/MySQL. What is the proper way for me to set that equal to a variable?

$style is equal to a value that is from a form (post).

When setting 'style' equal to a string value that is also in single quotes, I do not get an error. I only get an error when setting 'style' equal to a variable.

```
$query = "UPDATE `users` 
SET `style` = $style
WHERE `id` = $userid;";
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hopefully you're aware of [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), because you're probably highly vulnerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still have to put quotes around the variable as they are needed to tell MySQL that is a string. Remember, the variables are interpolated *before* the query is sent to the MySQL server. So `$style` is replaced by it's value before the query is run.

```
$query = "UPDATE `users` 
SET `style` = '$style'
WHERE `id` = $userid;";
```